# Create menu with multiple lines in assembly language program

Tags: assembly

My goal is to display a menu of 4 choices, name, age, major and exit.  For some reason, I am blanking on how to display this as a menu with each choice on a separate line.  It should look like this:

Please select a choice:
    1. Name
    2. Age
    3. Major
    4. Exit

I've gotten so used to the Java way of life and using \n within the string to push the text to the next line.  It is in 8086.

Comment: What type of assembly : 8086, MIPS, arm, altera, etc.?

Comment: Sorry the assembly is 8086

Comment: Add 13,10 (the literal numbers, outside the quotes) at the end of every string, instead of \n. Make the try and let us know.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/259cc6d19c38dfeb4ebe2382e299514a.png  This is the error that I am getting...Hmm

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made with EMU8086 :

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

menu db "Please select a choice:",13,10
     db "1. Name",13,10
     db "2. Age",13,10
     db "3. Major",13,10
     db "4. Exit",13,10,'$'

.code
start:

;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  call clear_screen      
  call display_menu    

;WAIT FOR ANY KEY.    
  mov  ah, 7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

;---------------------------------------------

display_menu proc
  mov  dx, offset menu
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
display_menu endp

clear_screen proc
  mov  ah, 0
  mov  al, 3
  int  10H
  ret
clear_screen endp

end start
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that problem!  It now runs and it displays the appropriate information when I select a choice.  Unfortunately I need the program to display the menu again to be ready for another choice..this is my next problem to figure out haha

Comment: I added the procedure to display the menu, just call it anywhere and anytime you need it, even better if you clear the screen before.